# python numpy access elements in 1d array with 2 indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I am writing a function that takes in a list of coordinates p[x,y] and perform some calculations. I would like to access the list of x's and y's using numpy indices:

```
p = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
x = p[:,0]
array([1, 3, 5])
```

However, when p only contains 1 row of coordinates, i.e. 1d array, the 2 index would result in an error.

```
p = np.array([1,2])
x = p[:,0]
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

I would like it to return the one value from the array.
Is there a way of indexing such that it works for both 1d and 2d arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `...` instead of `:` if you want to specify a variable number of dimensions (including none):

```
In [7]: p = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
In [8]: p[...,0]
Out[8]: array([1, 3, 5])
In [9]: p = np.array([1,2])
In [10]: p[...,0]
Out[10]: array(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Would it work to always create a 2d array like this?

```
p = np.array([[1,2], ])
```

Alternatively, you could look for the shape and only index that way if it is 2d.